# Equivalence of "A except that B." and "Except that B, A."

Tags: grammaticality

> 1: *He is nice* except that *he is a little shy*.
>
> 2: Except that *he is a little shy*, *he is nice*.

Are these sentences both correct? If so, are these two sentences identical?

Comment: To me the sentences seem grammatically correct, they also have the similar meaning for me (person is nice with one flaw (according to the speaker) - his shyness).

Comment: @Vilmar Doesn't the order matter in transition? As in, sentence 1 stressing the shyness while sentence 2 the niceness?

Comment: Does being shy in any way detract from being nice?  If the answer is "no" than I think the usage is not appropriate in this example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say they're questionable at a more complex level than pure syntax. Obviously, '[sentence A] except that [sentence B]', with punctuation adjusted as required, cannot be claimed to be non-syntactical – there is an example from AHD below.
This usage of *except that* as a conjunction means

> but for the fact that [= 'only' when used in this sense][a comma may be necessary] [Collins]
>
> I would buy the suit, except that it costs too much. [AHD]

If the Collins definition is exhaustive, 'He is nice except that he is a little shy.' is wrong because 'He is nice were it not for the fact that he is a little shy.' is wrong. 
I'd prefer 'only' here, in its 'but there is a minor negative:' sense

> He is nice, only he is a little shy.

And 'only' can't be fronted here. 'Although' could be.

Comment: It doesn't look like you directly answered the original questions: Are both forms grammatical and do they mean the same thing?

Comment: Right; my point was more that your answer didn't directly point that out. But it would be great if it did! :)